# Joining on the same table to get 2 different amount values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the total amount of a funding source (dim_6) against 2 different account codes (1301 AND 1300).

Below is the query that I designed.

```
SELECT t.dim_6,sum(t.amount) as bvalue, sum(t1.amount) as b1value   
FROM agltransact t
LEFT OUTER JOIN agltransact t1  ON t.dim_6 =t1.dim_6 
WHERE
t.dim_6 ='AWD-000261' and t1.dim_6='AWD-000261'  and (t.period between '201801' and '202102') and (t1.period between '201801' and '202102')
and t.account = '1300' and t.voucher_type!='YE' 
and t1.account = '1301' and t1.voucher_type!='YE'
```

The above query doesn't return the correct sum of amount and it doesn't match the value of amount if I try to run a simple SQL query against 1 account code, as below

```
 select dim_6,sum(amount) from agltransact where dim_6= 'AWD-000261' and voucher_type!='YE' and period between '201801' and '202102' and account ='1300' group by dim_6
```

Both the above queries have same conditions but the amount value doesn't matches if I JOIN.

What am I missing?

Comment: Suppose expected record from `t` is `1` & from `t2` are `2` then you will have total `2` rows where it would repeat record from `t` twice. So, `sum(t.amount)`  will be calculated twice instead of just once. Due to this you are getting incorrect values.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the total amount of a funding source (dim_6) against 2 different account codes (1301 AND 1300).

Just use conditional aggregation:

Below is the query that I designed.

```
SELECT t.dim_6,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.account = '1300' THEN t.amount END) as value_1300,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.account = '1301' THEN t.amount END) as value_1301
FROM agltransact t
WHERE t.dim_6 = 'AWD-000261' AND
      (t.period between '201801' and '202102') AND
      t.voucher_type <> 'YE' AND
      t.account IN ('1300', '1301')
GROUP BY dim_6;
```

Note:  I'm providing an answer because I think this is a *much better* solution than the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason your query do not work is** Suppose expected record from `t` is `1` & from `t2` are `2` then you will have total `2` rows where it would repeat record from `t` twice. So, `sum(t.amount)`  will be calculated twice instead of just once. Due to this you are getting incorrect values.

You need to separately run both queries and combine result like below. I have used [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for that.

```
;WITH t AS (
    select dim_6, sum(amount) as amount
    from agltransact 
    where dim_6= 'AWD-000261' 
        and voucher_type!='YE' 
        and period between '201801' and '202102' 
        and account ='1300' 
    group by dim_6
),
t1 AS (
    select dim_6, sum(amount) as amount
    from agltransact 
    where dim_6= 'AWD-000261' 
        and voucher_type!='YE' 
        and period between '201801' and '202102' 
        and account ='1301' 
    group by dim_6
)
select t.dim_6, t.amount as bvalue, t1.amount as b1value
from t
left outer join t1
    on t1.dim_6 = t.dim_6
```

---

Alternatively you can use sub query like below if you want to avoid `CTE`. Write `t1 cte as a sub query` and use `left join with t`. With `group by` of `t.dim_6, t1.amount`

```
select t.dim_6, sum(t.amount) as bvalue, t1.amount as b1value
from agltransact t
    left outer join (   
        select dim_6, sum(amount) as amount
        from agltransact 
        where dim_6= 'AWD-000261' 
            and voucher_type!='YE' 
            and period between '201801' and '202102' 
            and account ='1301' 
        group by dim_6      
    ) t1
        on t1.dim_6 = t.dim_6       
where t.dim_6= 'AWD-000261' 
    and t.voucher_type!='YE' 
    and t.period between '201801' and '202102' 
    and t.account ='1300' 
group by t.dim_6, t1.amount
```

Comment: Thank you Karan. I was actually trying to avoid CTE in this case since my original query is full of CTE's and this code itself is a part of CTE. But I guess there isn't any other alternative

Comment: Infact, I did a similar thing with another requirement without CTE and it worked as expected. Can you Suggest what could be the difference here?